# Global vars for development only in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack

I need to host a react app within a larger legacy application, which has some global variables that I would have access to upon being deployed (I reference the react app's js file after the js file with global vars is defined separately).

Obviously I get an error trying to build an app that's trying to reference undefined variables (not to mention I can't develop locally without being able to access them). What would be the best solution to workaround this issue / how could I inject these global vars (even dummy values) just for development?

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the work around for using the existing global variable in your react application.

**In Main.js (Entry point of your React App)**

Read the global variable from window object e.g. hostname

```
const hostName = window.hostname;
```

Pass it as a **props** to react component and then to all the components as **props** where ever required.

```
ReactDOM.render(<Page hostname={hostName} />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I would pass them in as props to my root component. That's the defacto way to get data into your React application in a structured way. However, I would also write some kind of adapter component that was able to read the global namespace and create props to pass into that root component. This way you could choose what to do in the event any one of those variables didn't exist or if you were in development, populate them with whatever value you want.

```
<GlobalVarAdapter variables={['name1', 'name2', 'name3']} />
```

Perform whatever logic you need inside GlobalVarAdapter to determine the env or fetch the global variables, then in the render function, pass those normalized values as props into your previous root component.

There are other ways to setup the GlobalVarAdapter so your root component can be 
declared as a child of GlobalVarAdapter and not embedded, but just importing it and rendering it with props is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `webpack` I'd suggest you to try [extended-define-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extended-define-webpack-plugin)

```
// webpack.config.js 
import ExtendedDefinePlugin from 'extended-define-webpack-plugin';

// pass NODE_ENV as env to the app
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const appGlobals = {env};
if (env !== 'production') {
  Object.assign(appGlobals, {
    foo: 'bar' //add whatever variables you need
  });
}

const webpackConfig = {
  // ... 
  plugins: [
    /* ..., */
    new ExtendedDefinePlugin(appGlobals)
  ]
}
```

All content of `appGlobals` will be accessible for entire webpack bundle